# Polymer 1.x + Firebase 2.x: How to push or put data to Firebase using Polymerfire?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer, polymerfire

Using Polymerfire, I want to add new nodes to a Firebase without overwriting data. (I call this `push` or `put` behavior.)

In other words. I want to start with this:

State A

```
my-app
 |
 - emails
    |
    + email1@example,com
    + email2@example,com
```

And finish with this.

State B

```
my-app
 |
 - emails
    |
    + email1@example,com
    + email2@example,com
    + email3@example,com
    + email4@example,com
```

But when I start with State A and do this:

```
<firebase-document
    id="doc"
    app-name="app"
    data="{{data}}">
</firebase-document>
...
this.$.doc.save('/', 'emails');
```

I wind up with this:

State B

```
my-app
 |
 - emails
    |
    + email3@example,com
    + email4@example,com
```

Notice the starting data: `email1@example,com` and `email2@example,com` were deleted.

[Here is the Polymerfire documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire?active=firebase-document). But it doesn't mention anywhere how to accomplish this type of `push` or `put`-type method to insert data into a node.

How can I accomplish this?

### Edit

[The answer by @motss suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724873/1640892):

```
this.$.doc('/emails');
```

instead of

```
this.$.doc('/', 'emails');
```

But that does not work because it adds a random auto key as follows:

State B

```
my-app
 |
 - emails
    |
    - -hvOxpxwjpWHBYGj-Pzqw
       |
       + email3@example,com
       + email4@example,com
```

Note the added key: `-hvOxpxwjpWHBYGj-Pzqw` thereby destroys the indexing feature of the data structure.

Comment: Far as I know the Firebase has a REST API so you should have a put and post method which can insert items to the node and because the Polymerfire is just wrapping the Firebase javascript you can use the Firebase javascript itself. Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: @Adamos42: [I see the `update()` method described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields). But there is no mention of it [in the Polymerfire docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire?active=firebase-document).

Comment: you have the `ref` and the `db` property which should return the `firebase.database().ref()` or the `firebase.database()` instance and after that you able to write your own code. It's sad that we don't have a proper Firabase element which can run any of the firebase api. In my projects I using the Firebase javascript API because it's way more documented than the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that the emails are used as keys for objects and are not an array (since you can't have arrays in a Firebase Realtime Database). If that's the case, you probably want something like:

```
<firebase-query
  id="emails"
  app-name="my-app"
  path="/emails"
  data="{{emails}}">
</firebase-query>
<script>
  // ...
  this.$.emails.ref.child('email3@example,com').set({new: 'data'});
  // ...
</script>
```

If you don't want to actually query the emails but just want to insert data, that's easy as well using the JS SDK:

```
firebase.database().ref('emails').child('email3@example,com').set({new: 'data'});
```

For a third option, you can use `<firebase-document>` with a path:

```
<firebase-document
  app-name="my-app"
  path="/emails/[[emailKey]]"
  data="{{emailData}}">
</firebase-document>
<script>
  // ...
  this.emailKey = 'email3@example,com';
  this.emailData = {new: 'data'};
  // ...
</script>
```

Comment: To anyone using this as an example: Note you have to replace the dot `.` with a comma `,` in the email address. So `email3@example.com` becomes `email3@example,com`. This is the best practice for Firebase because dots are not allowable characters in a Firebase key. And commas are not allowable characters in an email address. (Allowing a unique decode method.)

Comment: michaelbleigh: I have scoured the docs and made lots of attempts to try to take this to the next level using multiple paths and multiple nodes. But no success. [Could you please take a look at and consider answering this SO question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40749711/1640892)? (You and @FrankvanPuffelen seem to be the world's leading experts on this.)

Comment: Why don't use `encodeURIComponent` instead of replacing the original data with something else? [encodeURIComponentForFirebase](https://gist.github.com/motss/aae177f7a249db653e00e34214e51038)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `save` method does things differently in two ways:

1. To `set` new data into current location.
2. To `push` new data into current location.

In order to `push` new data, you have to submit no `key` as the second argument in the `save` method:

```
// This will push new data into the location /emails.
this.$.doc('/emails');

// To set new data (replacing) at location /emails.
this.$.doc('/', 'emails');
```

Hope this helps IIRC. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: That didn't work. It adds a random autokey. See edit.